# sql Count Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, count, group-by

I have a table name as JOB_Details and the data show as below:

```
Age           Department:IT         
              Male     Female 
30yrs         5          1              
30-34yrs      3          2              
35-39yrs      4          4              
40-49yrs      2          3              
50-54yrs      1          0
```

and the output suppose will like:

```
Age           Department:IT          Total
              Male     Female 
30yrs         5          1              6
30-34yrs      3          2              5
35-39yrs      4          4              8
40-49yrs      2          3              5
50-54yrs      1          0              1
Total         15         10             25
```

How can I do it? Because when using the count and group by function the result outcome will be not exactly what I want. Can someone mind to give me some suggestion? For your information I use Oracle.

Comment: SQL Server is not mysql is not oracle. Stop scattergunning and pick one.

Comment: Now I'm not sure what you're using. Is it SQL Server (Microsoft), MySQL or Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT AGE, MALE, FEMALE, SUM(MALE + FEMALE) AS TOTAL
FROM JOB_DETAILS
GROUP BY AGE
```

Edit:

If you want the running total you will have to use `ROLLUP` (SQL Server)

```
SELECT AGE, MALE, FEMALE, SUM(MALE + FEMALE) AS TOTAL
FROM JOB_DETAILS
GROUP BY AGE
WITH ROLLUP
```

Comment: +1, But what about the last row `Total         15         10             25
`

Comment: Because need to sum out the total as grand total.

Comment: @darren let said the number of male and female worker is not given?would you mind to suggest how i do it?because i count  by using the code as below:

Comment: SELECT (CASE WHEN age='30' THEN Count(EMPLID) 
         WHEN age='34' THEN Count(EMPLID)
         WHEN age='39' THEN Count(EMPLID)
         WHEN age='49' THEN Count(EMPLID)
         WHEN age='54' THEN Count(EMPLID)
         
        ELSE NULL END) TOTAL_COLUMN 

       ,(CASE WHEN GENDER1='M' THEN Count(EMPLID)
              WHEN GENDER1='F' THEN Count(EMPLID)
          ELSE NULL END) TOTAL_GENDER
         
FROM job_details
GROUP BY age,GENDER

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `union all` like this:

```
SELECT age, Male, Female, nvl(Male,0) + nvl(Female,0) as total
FROM JOB_Details 
union all
SELECT 'TOTAL', sum(Male), sum(Female), sum(nvl(Male,0) + nvl(Female,0))
FROM JOB_Details
```

With view:

```
create view vJOB_Details 
SELECT (CASE WHEN age='30' THEN Count(EMPLID) 
             WHEN age='34' THEN Count(EMPLID) 
             WHEN age='39' THEN Count(EMPLID) 
             WHEN age='49' THEN Count(EMPLID) 
             WHEN age='54' THEN Count(EMPLID) 
             ELSE NULL 
        END) TOTAL_COLUMN ,
        (CASE WHEN GENDER1='M' THEN Count(EMPLID) 
              WHEN GENDER1='F' THEN Count(EMPLID) 
              ELSE NULL 
         END) TOTAL_GENDER 
FROM job_details 
GROUP BY age,GENDER 

SELECT age, Male, Female, nvl(Male,0) + nvl(Female,0) as total
FROM vJOB_Details 
union all
SELECT 'TOTAL', sum(Male), sum(Female), sum(nvl(Male,0) + nvl(Female,0))
FROM vJOB_Details;
```

Comment: let said the number of male and female worker is not given?would you mind to suggest how i do it?because i count by using the code as below:
SELECT (CASE WHEN age='30' THEN Count(EMPLID) WHEN age='34' THEN Count(EMPLID) WHEN age='39' THEN Count(EMPLID) WHEN age='49' THEN Count(EMPLID) WHEN age='54' THEN Count(EMPLID) ELSE NULL END) TOTAL_COLUMN ,(CASE WHEN GENDER1='M' THEN Count(EMPLID) WHEN GENDER1='F' THEN Count(EMPLID) ELSE NULL END) TOTAL_GENDER FROM job_details GROUP BY age,GENDER

Comment: It's totally another problem, You have to ask new question, with this query.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion i will create a new question.(^^)

Comment: You can also create a view with this query, and replace 'JOB_Details' in my query.